# Use facebook AdView to find the WebView of the banner presented - through reflection

Tags: android, facebook, reflection, webview, facebook-audience-network

I'm using the Facebook SDK, here is the area that I'm getting the desired 'Ad' object:

```
    adView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded(Ad ad) {
            // Ad loaded callback

        }
```

Where `adView` is an object of class `AdView` from `package com.facebook.ads`.

Facebook ad type that I'm using:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/android-banners

Will be glad to find the WebView of the banner through reflection (I want to use javascript to change the icon, for example, within the banner).

Thanks!

Comment: Please can you explain your issue in brief?

Comment: Find the containing WebView of the facebook AdView object.

Comment: You can't change the ads

Comment: @WizKid why not? I just need to find the containing WebView... Can you help me with that?

Comment: If Facebook wanted you to change them they would have an API for it. There would be no reason to use reflection or access the webview

Comment: I agree with your position :) But I'm here to try some stuff :) Could you provide me a way to access the web view - using reflection (although you are working there)? Be neutral here :)

Comment: I have no idea how to do it. Just wanted to warn you that you shouldn't be surprised if Facebook bans you from using Facebook ads.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try finding a field that WebView is one of its superclasses.
Iterate over all field with reflection and for each field construct a list of superclasses and check if WebView is present in that list.